# Fast way to move one vertex point to another in the UV/Image Editor?

Tags: texturing, uv, workflow

Is there a fast way to move one selected vertex point to another point in the *UV/Image Editor*?

You can select the target point, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, *Cursor to Selection*, select the point to be moved, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, and *Selection to Cursor*, but this takes a long time. Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can toggle the *Snap* tool in the UV Editor's header by clicking the magnet icon or using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>. Then click the popover dropdown beside it and enable the element snapping type of *Vertex*.

[image]

[image]

Instead of frequently toggling the *Snap* tool on and off by clicking the magnet icon, simply hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while manipulating the UVs to temporarily activate snapping. (You still have to make sure you are in *Vertex* snapping mode.)

Comment: @Keavon OK. I wonder if this is what you want? Or any other tricks?